# React, update/reset nested state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, setstate

i need to reset a state. I have:

```
console.log(this.state["status"].toBeDeleted) //0|22|15
```

I need to empty `this.state["status"].toBeDeleted`. I have tried with `this.setState` but I didn't managed.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try and how did it fail?  `this.setState` is indeed what you would use to update the state.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: You need to provide some more context.. Is it a functional component or a class component? What does the rest of the component look like in general? etc..

Comment: Failed because it's a nested property, as Amid Maraj said, and I couldn't find any examples. Thats the only uncommon feature my code has.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You might be running into this issue because toBeDeleted is a nested property. You can attempt the setState as following, which should work:

```
this.setState({
   ...this.state,
   status: {
      ...this.state["status"]
      toBeDeleted: undefined
   }
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, works great

Comment: Yay, awesome! Glad to hear :)